# Apache subdomain not working: uses real domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, virtualhost

Let's say I have domain.com and sub.domain.com.

**Domain.com**'s root should be **/var/www/domain_com/** and **sub.domain.com**'s root should be **/var/www/domain_com/sub/**.

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain_com:

```
<VirtualHost sub.domain.com>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain_com/sub/"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/subdomain-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/subdomain-access.log" combined
    <Directory "/var/www/domain_net/sub/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost domain.com>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain_com/"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/domain-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/domain-access.log" combined

    <Directory "/var/www/domain_net/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Currently, I get this when I do to sub.domain.com/img.png:

```
[Sat Apr 09 01:14:41 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/domain_com/img.png, referer: http://sub.domain.com/img10.png
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't sub.domain.com/img.png serve from /var/www/domain_com/sub/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For name-based virtual hosting to work correctly, you need to match your bind address for the `<VirtualHost>` blocks to what's configured in the `NameVirtualHost` directive.  Name-based hosting isn't happening, so the first block to take the address is getting all requests.

Typically, you will have a directive like this somewhere in your Apache config files (ports.conf is common, when the config is split):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Which means you want the vhosts that will be distributing requests by name should match what's being set there:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    # (you might want this too):
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

By the way, why are your `<Directory>` directives controlling just `domain_net` and not `domain_com`?

Comment: This worked! Things I did wrong:
The Virtualhost line should read <VirtualHost *:80>, Not <VirtualHost domain>.
Also the line 
#NameVirtualHost *:80 should be mentioned exactly once.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
into /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default add the line bellow
NameVirtualHost *

# execute the command 
httpd -S 
# look at how many virtual hosts do you have enabled do ur request 
# and check the logs
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I noticed my ubuntu systems don't call apache2 'httpd' (-bash: httpd: command not found).
To use httpd on ubuntu, try apache2 instead.